# Debtor owes me, trying to figure out how to freeze RBC account

Tags: canada, debt

Through the summer, I picked up a client on a contract basis for whom I completed about 3 months of work. I had every reason to believe they would come good in terms of paying me, as the owners of the company are associated with other reputable firms. After not having gotten paid and having gotten a ton of excuses and even some bullying, I decided to sue the corporation in Alberta small claims. I won default judgement as they didn't file a response.

With the judgement in hand, and the knowledge that they have a bank account with RBC, I am trying to figure out my next move. There are about ~100 RBC branches in Calgary and trying to narrow down their home branch won't be trivial. I know RBC has a main branch in Calgary - but I am seeing conflicting information about whether they can help me out.

I am also trying to figure out their clients that may owe them money to try to garnish that way. Does anyone have any experience or suggestions they can share that would help me?

Comment: How long did it take the courts to process your claim from initiation to conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

In the United States you would issue a writ of garnishment to the bank with a copy by mail to the judgment debtor.

I suspect that the process is similar to this in Albert with a small claims court judgment, since it is also a common law jurisdiction, but I don't know this for a fact.